# Why Validating event handler cannot be used with async/await (C#)?

Tags: c#, async-await, validating

A have a simple textbox and I await a Delay Task inside a Validating handler. The Validated handler is always called, independently of whether I have `e.Cancel = true` or not! Note that if I omit the await call, validation occurs as expected. Why does this happen?

```
private async void textBox1_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Delay(2000);

    e.Cancel = true;
}

private void textBox1_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("THIS WILL ALWAYS BE CALLED!");
}
```

Comment: Do you really need to use `Validated` event? Just run everything in `Validating`.

Comment: @Sinatr This is what I finally did... I just wanted to know an explanation about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code that triggers the event is going to check the value of `e.Cancel` as soon as the event has finished calling all of the event handlers.  Since your code ends up returning from the event handler and then changing the value of `e.Cancel` *at a much later point in time*, the code that fired the event handler has already long since finished checking `e.Cancel` and determined whether or not the validation was successful by the time you're changing the value.

Comment: You may want to add that if you set `e.Cancel` to true before `await`ing anything, then it will be set when the caller checks the value since the code will run synchronously until any `await`s.

Comment: @clcto, why don't you post this finding as an answer? Setting `e.Cancel` before `await` indeed will solve the issue, as `Validated` will not be called.

Comment: @Sinatr It's not going to solve the problem, as presumably the asynchronous operation (in the real code) is determining if the item is valid.  If the asynchronous operation *isn't* used in determining if the control is valid then it could just be omitted entirely, which as the OP mentions themselves, solves the problem.

Comment: In fact, I want to await a Task, the result of which will define if the e.Cancel should be set to true or false. This is why I do not set e.Cancel before the await call.

Comment: @Servy yes you are right. I was thinking more for other events such as closing, where you can cancel, await, and then call close if necessary: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16656523/awaiting-asynchronous-function-inside-formclosing-event