# Wait for eventhandlers, if it is declared async

Tags: c#, async-await, event-handling, task

I have the following class

```
public class Foo
{
    private string? _bar;
    public event EventHandler<CancelPropertyChangingEventArgs>? CancelPropertyChanging;
    public string? Bar
    {
        get => _bar;
        set
        {
            if (CancelPropertyChanging is { } cancelPropertyChanging)
            {
                var eventArgs = new CancelPropertyChangingEventArgs()
                {
                    Cancel = false,
                    NewValue = value,
                    OldValue = _bar,
                    PropertyName = nameof(Bar),
                };
                cancelPropertyChanging(this, eventArgs);
                if (eventArgs.Cancel)
                    return;
            }

            _bar = value;
        }
    }

    public override string ToString() => Bar ?? "";
}
```

Where I can register to the event `CancelPropertyChanging` and potentially cancel a setter.

Everything works as expected when no `async/await` is involved.

With the following code.

```
var foo = new Foo();
foo.Bar = "Init Value";
foo.CancelPropertyChanging += Foo_CancelPropertyChanging;

foo.Bar = "Hello World";
foo.Bar = "Hello World 2";
Console.WriteLine(foo.Bar);
Console.WriteLine(foo.Bar == "Hello World 2" ? "Error" : "Correct");

void Foo_CancelPropertyChanging(object? sender, CancelPropertyChangingEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Changing Sync - OldValue: {e.OldValue} | NewValue: {e.NewValue}");

    if (Convert.ToString(e.NewValue) == "Hello World 2")
        e.Cancel = e.Cancel || true;
}
```

I am getting this output:

```
Changing Sync - OldValue: Init Value | NewValue: Hello World
Changing Sync - OldValue: Hello World | NewValue: Hello World 2
Hello World
Correct
```

So I did successfully `Cancel` the setting of `Hello World 2` into the `Bar` property of my `Foo` object.

The same code will fail when I declare the event handler `async` and introduce a `await Task.Delay(1_000);`

How could I `await` for all event handlers to really finish even if they are declared as `async`?

There isn't really a way to just say

```
await cancelPropertyChanging(this, eventArgs);
```

I wouldn't know if someone somewhere would register an event handler and mark it `async` and does what not, the second this happens my code will give undesired results.

Here you may find a demo of the code above:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/GWhk3w

**Notice:**

That this code demonstrates the issue at hand in the easiest setup I could think of, the acutal issue is more meaning full than a cancable setter, but it revolves around events and the ability to cancel, where I am facing the wrong cancel signal.

**Edit:**

A maybe realistic example would be.

Imagine you have a WPF window and register to the `Closing` event, which has a `Cancel` member.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.closing?view=windowsdesktop-6.0

No one would stop me from writing this

```
async void WpfWindow_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Delay(10_000);
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

How does the `Window` - if it actually does - wait for this code to finish to know if I set the `Cancel` member, and actually cancel the close of the window.

Comment: Does the `CancelPropertyChanging` event have to be of type `EventHandler<CancelPropertyChangingEventArgs>`, or is there flexibility on that?

Comment: @madreflection - as long as I could register something and can say .Cancel = true, I am open for changes

Comment: @madreflection - updated the question, with a maybe more practical example

Comment: You also have to consder that a proper handler for this would have to be async, and properties can't be async. You would have to have a method with a signature like `Task SetBar(string? value)` so you can await the event handler(s) correctly. That still meets the "register something and say .Cancel = true;" requirement, but it starts to deviate from your intended use as a property.

Comment: `EventHandler<T>` does not return anything, so there will be nothing to await. Even if it were to return `Task`, potentially you would have multiple event handlers attached to the same event, and it would only return the last. There is a reason for async event handlers being called "fire and forget". Simply put, you can't use `EventHandler<T>` for this.

Comment: @madreflection - I actually believed that event handlers are magic in this regard, so I was surprised it just didn't work out of the box

Comment: Additionally, there would be no safe way to call it inside the property setter anyway, as properties can't have async accessors. As such, you would have to fiddle with sync over async, doing "tricks" such as `.ConfigureAwaiter(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult()`, with the potential to deadlock. This is not recommended. In short, async event handlers will not be usable for you.

Comment: You're probably looking for something like this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/VBjELQ .  If that's okay, I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: @madreflection - wrote the question seconds before leaving office, please be patient with me going to evaluate it tomorrow

Comment: As a side note, `b || true` is `true`, so `e.Cancel = e.Cancel || true;` can be reduced to `e.Cancel = true;`. The only reason to logically combine in that manner is if you had another variable that could have either value. Something to think about in the meantime.

Comment: These two questions might be a bit relevant: [Awaiting Asynchronous function inside FormClosing Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16656523/awaiting-asynchronous-function-inside-formclosing-event) / [.NET Async in shutdown methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58406366/net-async-in-shutdown-methods)

Comment: @madreflection - about the bool copy and paste error, I simply copied the line from my real code and changed false to true without thinking - the idea of `e.Cancel = e.Cancel || false;` is to keep the true in e.Cancel instead of overwriting it with false

Comment: @madreflection - had a look at your code looks nice, and seems to do what I am looking for, feel free to move it to an answer, though I must say, it would only solve the issue around my own events and wouldn't help with the window closing problem

Comment: @madreflection - just noticed that your solution is the paragraph `The Task-Returning Delegate Solution` on Stephen's Blog

Comment: Interesting. I hadn't read the blog yet. I'm not going to write an answer, if Stephen Cleary has answered *and* covered it in the linked blog.

Comment: `e.Cancel = e.Cancel || false;` is functionally a no-op. If that's the statement for an `if` condition, just use empty braces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How does the Window - if it actually does - wait for this code to finish to know if I set the Cancel member, and actually cancel the close of the window.

It doesn't.

The normal pattern there is to *always* cancel the close of the window (possibly replacing it with a "hide" instead of close), do the (asynchronous) operation, and then do the actual close.

> How could I await for all event handlers to really finish even if they are declared as async?

Well, [there *are* ways to do this](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/02/async-oop-5-events.html), as noted on my blog. But here's the thing: your event-invoking code must `await` for all the handlers to complete one way or another. And since you can't `await` in a property setter, `await`ing the event handlers won't do you any good.

Like the WPF workaround, the best solution is probably a broader re-design. In this case, you can introduce the idea of (a queue of) pending changes that are only applied after all asynchronous checks have been done.