# Cancelling window closing with a task. How can I detect if task returned synchronously?

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await

I am following a fairly common pattern for confirming/canceling my main window closing with an async dialog method. However, in the async task that I call to present the dialog, there are conditions where I return a boolean value immediately instead awaiting the return of a dialog task method. In those cases an exception is thrown:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot set Visibility to Visible or call Show, ShowDialog, Close, or WindowInteropHelper.EnsureHandle while a Window is closing.'

It *seems* that this is because the async task is returning synchronously and calling Close() on the window instead of calling the rest of the code as a continuation. Besides just wrapping Close() in a try/catch or adding a Task.Delay() in my function before returning my bool, is there a way to detect if I should call Close() on my window? (ie. if the task returned synchronously)

Or...am I conceptually missing something in the async/await pattern?

Here is my code:

```
private bool _closeConfirmed;

private async void MainWindow_OnClosing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    //check if flag set
    if(!_closeConfirmed)
    {
        //use flag and always cancel first closing event (in order to allow making OnClosing work as as an async function)
        e.Cancel = true;

        var cancelClose = await mainViewModel.ShouldCancelClose();

        if(!cancelClose)
        {
            _closeConfirmed = true;
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's what the async function looks like:

```
public async Task<bool> ShouldCancelClose()
{
    if(something)
    {
        var canExit = await (CurrentMainViewModel as AnalysisViewModel).TryExit();

        if (!canExit) //if user cancels exit
            return true;

        //no exception
        return false;
    }

    //this causes exception
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Awaiting Asynchronous function inside FormClosing Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16656523/awaiting-asynchronous-function-inside-formclosing-event) It's not WPF, but it looks like they `await Task.Yield()` before their actual `async` function.

Comment: Also, you should be able to just do `Closing -= MainWindow_OnClosing` before your call to `Close()` instead of the whole `_closeConfimed` flag thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The exception is saying that you cannot call `Close()` while the `OnClosing` event is in the process of running. I think you understand that.

There are two ways to handle this.

**First**, the answer mentioned by Herohtar in the comments used [`await Task.Yield()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.yield?view=netframework-4.8).

More specifically, the key is awaiting *any incomplete `Task`*.

The reason is because **`async` methods start running synchronously**, just like any other method. The `await` keyword only does anything significant if it is given an incomplete `Task`. If it is given a `Task` that is already completed, *the method continues synchronously*.

So let's walk through your code. First let's assume that `something` is `true`:

1. `MainWindow_OnClosing` starts running, synchronously.
2. `ShouldCancelClose` starts running synchronously.
3. `TryExit()` is called and returns an incomplete `Task`.
4. The `await` keyword sees the incomplete `Task` and returns an incomplete `Task`. Control is returned to `MainWindow_OnClosing`.
5. The `await` in `MainWindow_OnClosing` sees an incomplete `Task`, so it returns. Since the return type is `void`, it returns nothing.
6. Control is returned to the form, and since it cannot await the rest of `MainWindow_OnClosing`, it assumes the event handler is finished.
7. Whenever `TryExit()` finishes, the rest of `ShouldCancelClose` and `MainWindow_OnClosing` runs.
8. If `Close()` is called now, it works, because **as far as the form knows, the event handler finished at step 6**.

Now let's assume that `something` is `false`:

1. `MainWindow_OnClosing` starts running, synchronously.
2. `ShouldCancelClose` starts running synchronously.
3. `ShouldCancelClose` returns a completed `Task` with a value of `false`.
4. The `await` keyword in `MainWindow_OnClosing` sees the completed `Task` and continues running the method *synchronously*.
5. When `Close()` is called, it throws the exception **because the event handler has not finished running**.

So using `await Task.Yield()` is just a way to await *something incomplete* so that control is returned to the form so it thinks the event handler has finished.

**Second**, if you know that no asynchronous code has run, then you can rely on `e.Cancel` to cancel the closing or not. You can check by not awaiting the `Task` until you know if it's complete or not. That could look something like this:

```
private bool _closeConfirmed;

private async void MainWindow_OnClosing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    //check if flag set
    if(!_closeConfirmed)
    {

        var cancelCloseTask = mainViewModel.ShouldCancelClose();

        //Check if we were given a completed Task, in which case nothing
        //asynchronous happened.
        if (cancelCloseTask.IsCompleted)
        {
            if (await cancelCloseTask)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
            else
            {
                _closeConfirmed = true;
            }
            return;
        }

        //use flag and always cancel first closing event (in order to allow making OnClosing work as as an async function)
        e.Cancel = true;

        if(!await cancelCloseTask)
        {
            _closeConfirmed = true;
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any need for the `_closeConfirmed = true;` in the case where `cancelCloseTask.IsCompleted` is true...

Comment: @Herohtar Yeah I guess, because the form will be destroyed right after anyway. Makes sense.